# Resizing disk partitions - Debian 10

Tags: debian, disk, fdisk

I would like to resize my partitions in order to have the following configuration:

- 30 Go for the user repertory
- 45 Go for /var/lib/ repertory
- 45 Go for /opt/ repertory

However I don't understand how to rebuild the partition's configuration with fdisk.

I am on Debian 10.

The current configuration is the following:
[image]

Comment: It seems that `/opt` and `/var` are all on the same partition. Why is `sda2` not mounted? What's on there? You can't resize partitions that don't exist

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Indeed, currently opt and var are on the same partition. However I suppose it is necessary to first split partitions (30Go/45Go/45Go before  to move those folders ? Everything is in the cloud, those are not physical hd